# separator color to white in swiftui iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, ios14

Xcode 12 iOS 14 Swift UI
How to change separator color in List, Please look at below code

```
struct SettingMenu: View {
var settings: [Setting] = SettingItems.options
var body: some View {
    List{
        ForEach(settings, id: \.self) { setting in
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: setting.imageName)
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                Text(setting.title)
                    .font(.callout).foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
        }.listRowBackground(Color(red: 62 / 255, green: 56 / 255, blue: 104 / 255)).cornerRadius(25)
        
    }
    .onAppear() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine
        
    }
}
}
```

I tried  `UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = UIColor.white` but its not working for me.

thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a normal list then use LazyVStack.

Comment: Try moving those settings to `init()` rather than onAppear.